# Does a foreign key constraint automatically disallow nulls?

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

In my Activities table I have a StaffId field. This is a FK of the Staff table (that holds StaffId). On inserting data into the Activities table - if the StaffId is null it throws a FK constraint error!? I have ticked the 'Alllow Nulls' box in SSMS so why is this not the case?

Note, this record is being inserted through the DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery method.

Also note: I have just ran an Insert statement using SSMS to insert NULL values, and it worked. May be this is a more C# specific question!?

Comment: Yes FKs do allow `NULL` if the column is nullable for optional relationships. Sure it's that FK it is complaining about?

Comment: I remember that a fk column could be null, maybe it's due to SSMS' limit?

Comment: `FK_Activities_Staff` - and it's the only FK that is on any other table. Baffles me this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference
>   the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table. A FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint can contain null values; however, if any column of a
>   composite FOREIGN KEY constraint contains null values, verification of
>   all values that make up the FOREIGN KEY constraint is skipped. To make
>   sure that all values of a composite FOREIGN KEY constraint are
>   verified, specify NOT NULL on all the participating columns.

you can see another example in MySql, look at the following link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
You can see that it is possible to SET NULL

> SET NULL: Delete or update the row from the parent table and set the
>   foreign key column or columns in the child table to NULL. This is
>   valid only if the foreign key columns do not have the NOT NULL
>   qualifier specified. Both ON DELETE SET NULL and ON UPDATE SET NULL
>   clauses are supported.
>
> If you specify a SET NULL action, make sure that you have not declared
>   the columns in the child table as NOT NULL.

Comment: Why "No"? The passage you quote says "Yes"!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Dor Cohen. There is no unique constraint as mentioned in your first quote so it can't be that. There is a unique constraint on StaffId on the Staff table obviously but the StaffId can be referenced many times on the Activities table (I may have misunderstood your answer here).

Comment: Right, I'm completely confused now. Basically - the StaffId table obviously cannot be null on the Staff table, and it is obviously unique. On the Activities table, the StaffId field WILL allow Nulls (according to the 'Allow Nulls' checkbox) but behaves otherwise when attempting to insert a null from C#.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Any particular bit? It clearly states "A FOREIGN KEY constraint can contain null values". Which I knew already to be the case.

Comment: @MartinSmith and another that +1 him: my quote contains: "A FOREIGN KEY constraint can contain null values" so how it's say Yes?? please remove your comment

Comment: @MartinSmith: Well, the question is "Does a foreign key constraint automatically disallow nulls?" and the answer is "No", because "A FOREIGN KEY constraint can contain null values". Why should it be "Yes"? That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Ah I see, we are all in agreement then but I thought the question asked if they were allowed.

Comment: @MartinSmith: That's what I meant when I said "Read again" :-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - I see! I read the answer again but didn't help!

Comment: this doesn't solve the C# problem at all. And why are you providing mySQL examples if the DB is SQl Server?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do on the DB as @Martin demonstrated. The problem is on your front end. DbCommand has issues dealing with NULLs, that's one of the reasons they created Linq To Sql.

I suggest you try something like this:

```
if(parameter_is_not_null)
      db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "staffId", DbType.String, staffId.Text);
else
      db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "staffId", DbType.String, DBNull.Value);
```